# Using Scanner in Java

Tags: java, string, file, java.util.scanner, long-integer

Writing a class that reads n .csv file and creates the objects "Account".
This is a test.

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class AccountTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("1234567890989.csv");
        Scanner scanner;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);

            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                scanner.nextLine();
                scanner.next("Account");
                String pp = scanner.next();

                System.out.println(pp);

            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

File:

```
Account Info - 14-03-2014
Account  ;1234567890989 ; EUR  ;POUPANCA ;SavingsAccount ;
Start Date ;31-10-2013
End Date ;03-01-2014
Date ;Value Date ;Description ;Draft ;Credit ;Accounting     balance ;Available balance 
31-10-2013 ;31-10-2013 ;SUMMARY ;0.0 ;200.0 ;2600.0 ;2600.0
30-11-2013 ;30-11-2013 ;SUMMARY ;0.0 ;200.0 ;2800.0 ;2800.0
31-12-2013 ;31-12-2013 ;SUMMARY ;0.0 ;200.0 ;3000.0 ;3000.0
02-01-2014 ;02-01-2014 ;TRANSF ;0.0 ;300.0 ;3300.0 ;3300.0
02-01-2014 ;02-02-2014 ;TRANSF ;0.0 ;300.0 ;3600.0 ;3600.0
03-01-2014 ;03-01-2014 ;TRANSF ;0.0 ;300.0 ;3900.0 ;3900.0
```

Returns ';1234567890989' but I want to have only '1234567890989' and format it to Long.

Comment: CSV is comma seperated.  Your input is colon seperated.

Comment: define "format it to long".  1234567890989 is a long (the java primitive type) value.

Comment: @DwB, CSV can also mean "_character_ separated value". It's a terribly poorly defined file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work -

```
if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {            // Check for the line.
    scanner.nextLine();                 // read the line.
    if (scanner.hasNext("Account")) {   // Check for account.
        scanner.next("Account");        // read the field.
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {        // Check if there is more.
            String pp = scanner.next(); // read it.
            if (pp.startsWith(";")) {   // remove a leading ';'
                pp = pp.substring(1);
            }
            long lpp = Long.parseLong(pp);  // convert to long.
            System.out.println(lpp);        // print it.
        }
    }
}
```

Output is

```
1234567890989
```

Comment: This code may extract the account number from the file, but it is not particularly helpful for the OP's ultimate goal of creating `Account` objects (which will presumably require the entire file to be parsed).

Comment: @BrianS If you go and change the question, then sure! I'd probably use a `StringTokenizer` (or add an `Account` constructor that takes then entire line).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
String pp = scanner.next();
String qq;

qq = StringUtils.strip(StringUtils.trim(pp), ";");
```

StringUtils is part of [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/)

`strip` removes characters from the start and end of the string,
so be sure to trim whitespace before calling strip.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Scanner` uses whitespace as a delimiter. Thus, `Scanner.next` is looking at all those spaces in your file and separating your values by that, and thus you're capturing the semicolons.

You can change the delimiter being used with the `useDelimiter` method. Something along these lines should work:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("1234567890989.csv")).useDelimiter(";");
while (scanner.hasNext())
{
    String token = scanner.next();
    ...
}
```

To transform your token into a `long`, you'll have to decide whether the token *should be* a long, and then use `Long.parseLong(token)`.